# Kendo Mobile - Flat Skin - Portrait to Landscape Clipping

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

The following issue is specific to Android -

I have set up a very basic test case using the following html:

```
    <div data-role="view">
    </div>


    <!-- Master Layout -->
    <div data-role="layout" data-id="masterLayout">
        <header data-role="header">
            <div data-role="navbar">
                <span data-role="view-title">Demo</span>
                <a data-role="button" data-icon="details" data-align="right"></a>
            </div>
        </header>


        <footer data-role="footer">
            <div data-role="tabstrip">
                <a data-icon="search">Search</a>
                <a data-icon="home">Home</a>
                <a data-icon="action">Action</a>
            </div>
        </footer>
    </div>
```

The page renders correctly in both portrait and landscape mode. If the page is loaded in portrait mode, and then switched to landscape mode, a small amount of clipping occurs on the entire right side of the page (including the header and footer). Loading the page in landscape, then switching to portrait, then back to landscape does not encounter this error.

Could this be a bug in Kendo Mobile? I am currently using version 2013.2.906 with jQuery 1.9.1. Tested on Nexus 7 (1st gen) and transformer Prime (model 201), using both the stock Browser and latest Google Chrome Browser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try with 2013.2.910 from today?

Comment: Annnnnnd we're back! Thanks for the update on today's fresh build. I can confirm this issue is fixed on both the Transformer Prime and Nexus 7 tablets, running both Stock Browser and Google Chrome Browser.

Comment: Unfortunately, while this build did provide a fix to my issue, another issue has crept in. When a modal view is opened, and the screen is rotated, the modal view no longer re-centers itself to the screen based on the new rotated view.